# Changing SET to ENUM in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, enums, set, mysql-5.0

I have a `SET` field which hit the limit of 64 (I was a newbie while I was designing the database few years ago). Now I cannot add more `SET` values to my `department` field. I'm thinking to change it into `ENUM` type. What can I do?

MySQL 5.0.95

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alter table `table_name` change column_name new_column_name enum('a','b','c','d');
```

new column name can be the same as old. values probably should be the same, or at least there should be every old value from set type and some new that you want to add.